# Reports are not generating when Taurus Performance Test is executed using Jenkins

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, taurus

I am trying to execute the yaml script using Jenkins. I am using freestyle project and Windows Batch command as a Build Configuration.

```
bzt D:\NESTTest.jmx.yaml -report
```

I have added a Performance Plugin to view the reports generated after the test.
[image]

perf_result_csv.xml should get generated after the test run.

```
reporting:
- module: console
- module: final-stats
  summary: true
  percentiles: true 
  failed-labels: false
  test-duration: true
  dump-xml: perf_result_csv.xml
```

I am Receiving this error while executing the Build

> D:\Jenkins CICD\workspace\Taurus Project>exit 1  Build step 'Execute
>   Windows batch command' marked build as failure Cannot detect file type
>   **because of error:  Failed to copy** D:\Jenkins CICD\workspace\Taurus
>   Project\perf_result_csv.xml to D:\Jenkins CICD\jobs\Taurus
>   Project\builds\2\temp\perf_result_csv.xml

The script works fine when run manually from the command Prompt of Windows.

Comment: It is very likely that you would’ve figured out the problem by now, but it sounds to me like a permissions issue.